# How to get woocommerce price attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to get the following information on a woocommerce single product page in order to replace the default price style of woocommerce.

When Item is on sale, I want to be able to get the original price and discounted price and echo it inside a dive for further styling. Im trying to achive something like this.

```
<div id="orig-price">Original Price: <?php echo $price; ?></div>
<div id="sale-price">Sale Price: <?php echo $sale-price; ?></div>
<div id="saved">You saved: <?php $saved=$price-$saleprice; echo $saved; ?></div>
```

I tried opening price.php but did not find what I am looking for. here is what I get.

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />
    <div><?php echo $sale_price_in_percent; ?></div>

</div>
```

Am I on the right place? Anyone know how can I access these attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Main function for displaying prices is `get_price_html()` in `/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php` file, and there are some filters to allow users to customize the html for prices:

- woocommerce_sale_price_html
- woocommerce_price_html
- woocommerce_empty_price_html
- woocommerce_free_sale_price_html
- woocommerce_free_price_html
- woocommerce_get_price_html

This function performs a complete job for showing prices including taxes and on sale calculations, and since you are completely rewriting the html the example below uses last filter there woocommerce_get_price_html. It extracts the prices from the original HTML and insert them into a new HTML structure.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', function( $price, $product ) 
{ 
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // check if we are in single product page, in main section, and if product has price and is on sale
    if ( is_product() && !isset( $woocommerce_loop ) && $product->get_price() && $product->is_on_sale() ) {

        // collect prices from $price html string
        $prices = array_map( function( $item ) {        
            return array( $item, (float) preg_replace( "/[^0-9.]/", "", html_entity_decode( $item, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) ) );           
        }, explode( ' ', strip_tags( $price ) ) );

        $price = isset( $prices[0][0] ) ? '<span class="orig-price">Original Price: ' . $prices[0][0] . '</span>' : '';
        $price .= isset( $prices[1][0] ) ? '<span class="sale-price">Sale Price: ' . $prices[1][0] . '</span>' : '';

        if ( $product->get_regular_price() ) {
            // set saved amount with currency symbol placed as defined in options
            $price .= '<span class="saved">You saved: ' . sprintf( get_woocommerce_price_format(), get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(), $prices[0][1] - $prices[1][1] ) . '</span>';      
        }
    }

    return $price;

}, 10, 2 );
```

I'm using span tags here instead of divs used in question because the output is still wrapped in a paragraph. For further customization override the price.php template by placing him inside `/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/` folder.

Comment: Thanks. This seems working except for the saved amount. It does not show. Original price and sale price works well.

Comment: It does not show at all, or just amount, it worked well when i tested, sale amount is only shown for products that are on sale, and not for products with price variations or products on regular prices, btw. i'm using WC 2.1.5.

Comment: It does not show at all. see [link](http://demo.starpixel.net/passitforward/?product=sample-deal-2) there is only $200 and $150 which are orig price and sale price. How can I make it to output each on their own. not concatenated so I can put it in their proper places. Thanks

Comment: Use var_dump on $prices array to see what's happening, to output each on their own is quite tricky, you can use above listed filters for individual price formatting but at the end everything will be concatenated. If you want to explore deeper, open the abstract-wc-product.php file to see how prices are generated and to see which functions and actions are available.

Comment: this is the result of the vardump. `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "$200.00" [1]=> float(36200) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "$150.00" [1]=> float(36150) } }` there is no value of saved. also, why there is 36200 and 36150. shouldn't it be 200 and 150 only? why there is 36 in front of both float price? (orig price and sale price)

Comment: I must apologize for the confusion I created, I tested this example on a modified theme and normally it does not work as it should. The answer is updated and it should work now.

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot! var_dump gave me the full view of variables and I were able to seperate each of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by overriding woocommerce template. Create a new PHP file, write your div structure in that file.

Now refer this article on [How to override template in WooCommerce](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

Hope this will move you in right direction

Comment: The problem for now is getting the prices, then template overrides. I wnet to that documentation and it see price.php under templates and it show basic price. need to take sale price, discount, percent discount, etc. is there documentation for that?